# Take values from a <class 'list> and convert to integer

Tags: python, class, types, pyserial

I am reading data from an arduino using a class and extracting the digits from a byte array into the variable 'number'.

```
    number = ([int(s) for s in rl.readline().split() if s.isdigit()])
    print(number)
    print(type(number))
```

I get this output

```
[511]
<class 'list'>
```

How can I take this value [511] from this type "<class 'list'> and use it as an integer?
Thank you

Comment: Yes just want to take it out of the list, but if i try number[0] its says index is out of range

Comment: You can't get that error with the `number` that you showed in the question. `number[0]` is how you get the first element of the list though. Double check your data if you're getting that error.

Comment: print(number[0])
IndexError: list index out of range

This is the error I am receiving, I am not sure how

Comment: Yes, that means that `number` is empty. You can't get that error if `number` contains anything. As I mentioned, double check your data. Is the file already exhausted? Try reopening the file.

Comment: Ok i found that i was reading the data too fast, so i think it was overwriting before my computer could access the element in the list. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

```
# initializing list  
test_list = ['1', '4', '3', '6', '7'] 
  
# Printing original list 
print ("Original list is : " + str(test_list)) 
  
# perform conversion 
for i in range(0, len(test_list)): 
    test_list[i] = int(test_list[i]) 

# Printing modified list  
print ("Modified list is : " + str(test_list))

#output is given below
#Original list is : ['1', '4', '3', '6', '7']
#Modified list is : [1, 4, 3, 6, 7]
```